# Having trouble with python build email

Tags: python, email

I developed an email system for my client by using email.mime library. I works very well for some mail clients. For example on gmail I can see html body and attachment file but on yahoo I get an empty email.  Here is the code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
import email.charset

from email import Encoders
def buildEmail(from_email, to_email, subject, text_msg, html_msg, attach_pdf_file):
    """
    This function build a body for text/html message and if attachment file provide
    then it will attach it too with email.
    """

    # Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.

    msgRoot = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msgRoot['Subject'] = subject

    msgRoot.preamble = 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.'
    msgRoot.epilogue = ''


    # Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
    text_part = MIMEText(text_msg, 'plain')
    msgRoot.attach(text_part)

    if html_msg is not None and html_msg != '':
        html_part = MIMEText(html_msg, 'html')
        msgRoot.attach(html_part)


    # Attach a file if provided
    if attach_file is not None and attach_file != '':
        fp = open(attach_pdf_file, 'rb')
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'pdf')
        part.set_payload( fp.read() )
        Encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename="%s"%          os.path.basename(attach_pdf_file))
        msgRoot.attach(part)
        fp.close()


    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    s.sendmail(from_email, to_email, msgRoot.as_string())
    s.quit()
```

Any idea where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several problems with this code that should prevent it from working at all on Python 2.x.

1) You don't define `attach_file` anywhere, so this line raises an exception:

```
if attach_file is not None and attach_file != '':
```

Did you mean `attach_pdf_file`? Changing `attach_file` to `attach_pdf_file` corrects that exception.

2) Maybe you just left it out of your code sample, but you call a function from `os.path`, but you never `import os` anywhere in your script. Adding that corrects that exception.

Once those problems are corrected, running the script on my system with the `from` address as a gmail address raises this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ra/Desktop/stack-overflow.py", line 50, in <module>
    "output.pdf")
  File "/home/ra/Desktop/stack-overflow.py", line 44, in buildEmail
    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 249, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 309, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 284, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I don't have an SMTP server configured locally on this machine, which explains why I get the error I do. In your case, if the email is sending properly, but only for some email providers, it could be because an email provider realises that even though the *address* is Yahoo, the SMTP server isn't and thus refuses the email. It's just a hunch, but it might explain it (if this weren't the case, it would be even easier for anyone to send an email "from" any address).